# Skobbler mapview causes a native lib error when deleting an overlay during map actions

Tags: android, skmaps

For our app  I have to add/remove a polyline. First it was running quite well, but then, looking randomly, the app exits with:

```js
11-12 10:12:17.780: D/SKMaps(10210): SKMapSurfaceView---- Add polyline 
11-12 10:12:17.780: A/libc(10210): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b8 (code=1), thread 10376 (Thread-1347)
```

or sometimes this:

```js
11-12 10:35:56.176: D/SKMaps(4398): SKMapSurfaceView---- Add polyline 
11-12 10:35:56.176: A/libc(4398): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x834c9010 passed to dlfree
11-12 10:35:56.176: A/libc(4398): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 5060 (Thread-26355)
```

Looking deeper into the code I found out that this happened when a polyline was added and simultaneously a map action occurred (pan, zoom ...).
So my question is: am I right with my conclusion, and if so, how can I manage this without building a kind of map actions observer?

Comment: Are you able to replicate this behaviour/crash with the demo project?

Comment: Yes, and I found out that not adding causes the error, but deleting is the problem. Even without map actions, if the delay between adding and deleting is less than 40ms. I adapted the question so far.

Comment: If you can reproduce it with the demo project - please send the modified project to dev@skobbler.com. Thanks

Comment: Issues fixed for the 2.4 SDK update